# How can I disable mouse movement of a PyQtGraph legend?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm creating a simple PyQtGraph plot with a legend, and I'd like to disable all interactivity.

I'm able to disable panning and zooming as well as the right-click context menu, but the legend can still be moved. How can I prevent the user from dragging the legend around with the mouse?

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg

widget = pg.plot()

# Disable interactivity
widget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)  # Disable mouse panning & zooming
widget.hideButtons()  # Disable corner auto-scale button
widget.getPlotItem().setMenuEnabled(False)  # Disable right-click context menu

widget.addLegend(enableMouse=False)  # This doesn't disable legend interaction
widget.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4], name="Example plot")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legend itself implements two mouse events: `mouseDragEvent` and `hoverEvent`. To disable it, you can simply override it with lambda function, that does nothing.
Also, you might want to disable hide / show functionality of legend. This can be done by overriding `legend.sampleType.mouseClickEvent`.

Here is modified code you can use. I left `legend.sampleType.mouseClickEvent` commented out:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

widget = pg.plot()

# Disable interactivity
widget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)  # Disable mouse panning & zooming
widget.hideButtons()  # Disable corner auto-scale button
widget.getPlotItem().setMenuEnabled(False)  # Disable right-click context menu

legend = widget.addLegend()  # This doesn't disable legend interaction
# Override both methods responsible for mouse events
legend.mouseDragEvent = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
legend.hoverEvent = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
# Uncomment if you want to disable show / hide event of legend click
# legend.sampleType.mouseClickEvent = lambda *args, **kwargs: None


widget.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4], name="Example plot")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.exec()
```